# Are digital signatures enforceable (legally binding) across the EU?

Tags: european-union, digital-contract

While setting up an account with an online service I was told by support that I cannot complete the application because the country I'm based in has not enacted legislation accepting electronic signatures as enforceable.

I'm based in an EU member state (Bulgaria) and, as far as I can tell, due to the eIDAS (Electronic Identification, Authentication and Trust Services) regulation, electronic signatures are legally binding across the EU, including Bulgaria.

Is my understanding correct? If not, what am I missing?

PS according to the service I'm trying to set up an account with, there are a bunch of other EU member states that don't enforce digital signatures (Croatia, Cyprus, Estonia, Latvia, Luxembourg, Malta, Slovakia, Slovenia).

Comment: Weird. I know for fact that Luxembourg enforces digital signatures according to eidas (I literally work for a digital signature company in lux, and we are also required by state to digi-sign for some stuff).

Comment: @Mouke yeah, I think they just don't have a big enough legal team to keep track of that kind of stuff. The fact that these countries are relatively small markets compared to other EU states probably plays a role.